# what is the best way to insert repeating HTML blocks with small changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created list, but each element is a pretty big HTML chunk that has a common structure and a few variables.
What would be the best way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: Create a loop, with varying values [If you are inserting the same chunk of HTML elements but with different text/value], appened everything to a single variable and then insert it. If you do inserting inside the loop itself, it'll affect the performance since you are performing N DOM changes.

Comment: Please post some of your code - the structure of the list elements, the variables contained within, what you want to change...

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle large amounts of HTML in the client is to use atemplate system. If you want to keep it jQuery centric [then jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) are one option but I believe it has been dis-continued.

I've had a lot of success [with Underscore templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template), which are fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is overkill for you, but maybe check out a templating library.

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js is really good I've heard (personally haven't used it).

I've used the one from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)

The latter would look something like this..

```
var myTemplate = _.template("<div>This is my reusable block with {{ count }} variables");

$.each([1,2,3,4], function(elm, i){
  $('body').append(myTemplate ({count: elm}));
})
```

Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/K8VHb/

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo what CambridgeMike and Simon Smith said, "Use a template library," except that I'll plug a different and I think better one. Use [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). It's the same one Ember.js picked, it's great standalone and it pairs well with Backbone.js as well.

It's something you can use for a long time.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the join method of arrays (concatenates elements into strings) is my favorite approach. Using this along with JQ, I've never really understood the appeal of JS templating libraries. It's also convenient for formatting HTML in an easy-to-read style without sweating line-breaks in JavaScript. I didn't test this so there may be syntax goofs.

```
var standardList = [
    '<li>Always here</li><!--could add a bunch more non-variable LIs here-->',
    '<li>',
    , //this is key #2 - one comma per line at the end makes counting easy
    '</li>',
    '<li>More non-variable LIs</li><!--possibly more non-variable LIs here-->',
    '<li>',
    , //this is key #6
    '</li>'
];

//you could have lots of these or an array of them dropped in from a server
var variableListItems = {
    key_2:'first Var list value',
    key_6:'second variable list value'
};

function buildFromListTemplate(valuesObj,listTemplate){
    for(var x in valuesObj){
        listTemplate[x.split('_')[1]] = valuesObj[x];

        //x.split('_') returns array ['key',<number>] for each key in object
        //so [1] gives array key
    }
    return listArray.join(''); //smooshes array into one big string
}

$('#someExistingUL').html(
    buildFromListTemplate(variableListItems, standardList)
);
```

Note: A powerful but easy upgrade would be to handle the LI-wrapping of values inside the buildFromListTemplate function. That way, the keys you put inside your values object would all be optional and wouldn't leave a blank LI when not provided.

When it comes to formatting big hunks of HTML, split/join are your friend and have powerful utility in general. Another handy use is to build a list or table row from an existing set of values:

```
var ulHtmlString = [
'<ul><li>',
    arrayOfValues.join('</li><li>'),
'</li></ul>'
].join('')
```

You can build on this to auto-convert 2D arrays into tables as well. Learn some regEx (which can be used in place of strings in the split method) and you can easily convert back from HTML to data-only arrays and objects in cases where the HTML isn't uniform.

Answer (score -1):

i would use [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

using jquery templates consists of two pieces:

your template (usually HTML):

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div>${text} ${otherStuff}</div>
</script>
```

and your data (usually JSON or a javascript object):

```
var data = { text: 'hello world!', otherStuff: 'foobar' };
```

Then you just bind the data to the template

```
var resultingHTML = $('#myTemplate').tmpl(data);
```

then append the resulting HTML to your DOM:

```
$('#someContainer').append(resultingHTML);
```

jQuery templates offer a lot of flexibility with conditionals/loops in your templates such as {{if}} and {{each}}, and JSON is a very easy data transfer language to work with.

Comment: jQuery Templates is deprecated. I wouldn't recommend something that has already been marked for removal.

Comment: @JohnMunsch so you can sit on your thumb until jsView comes out, or you can consume the old template now and then seamlessly upgrade to jsView when it is released. seems like an easy decision to me.

Comment: We used jQuery Template ourselves before it was deprecated and when we tried to shift to JsViews it proved to be more of a thought experiment than a finished library with proper documentation and the ability to handle real world templates. So we actually gathered the URLs of more than 20 different JavaScript template libraries and reviewed them before deciding on Handlebars.js. You aren't restricted to just those two choices, and some of the competitors are in great shape compared to JsViews.

Comment: @JohnMunsch i would not consider your opinion of which template library to use as a valid reason to downvote an answer.